# "Springboard" figurative use equivalent in French?

Tags: traduction, anglais

En anglais on peut dire :

> *He saw the governor's office as a springboard to a national career.*

Où *springboard* signifie *starting point*.

Peut-on employer *tremplin* pour la traduction de cette phrase ? Si non, comment peut-on exprimer le même sens ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

*Tremplin* est tout à fait adéquat :

> Il voyait le cabinet du gouverneur comme un tremplin vers une carrière nationale.

Answer (score 0):

Voici un exemple  d'emploi pertinent

> L’EICnam tremplin pour une insertion professionnelle durable  : 70%
>   ont un emploi à la sortie de la formation 90% dans les 6 mois.... 10%
>   poursuivent leurs études...

Source

http://www.cnam-paca.fr/documents/plaquette-eicnam